# Anybody know what KM is?

Tags: additives, vinegar

I was browsing forums looking for any new tips to prevent wine from becoming vinegar (My last batch was ruined and want to make sure that does not happen again) and I stumbled cross this mysterious comment

[image]

The user who posted it is no longer active, and the website will not let me post on [this chain](https://www.winemakingtalk.com/threads/alcohol-content-to-prevent-vinegar.42411/).
Does anyone know what this mysterious KM is, and if it really completely removes the chance of making vinegar?

Thanks im advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the little bit of context I'm going to guess this is an odd/inaccurate shorthand for potassium metabisulfate.

Although the real shorthand is `K₂S₂O₅` they're likely using `k` to represent potassium and `m` for the metabisulfate.

Comment: Thanks! I am guessing I add this AFTER fermentation is complete, correct?

Comment: For stabilizing a fermented wine- yes you would put it after fermentation is complete.

Comment: I'd add that it is [very](https://beerandbrewing.com/dictionary/icjVak6iZV/) [common](https://www.midwestsupplies.com/blogs/bottled-knowledge/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-campden-tablets) to see potassium metabisulfite referred to as _KMS_

Comment: Interesting, coming from brewing I normally have just called it "Campden" or "campden tablets" as thats how it's typically sold in shops. Although I agree that KMS makes a lot of sense.